# I forgot that I soaked rice , urad , and chana?

Tags: food-safety

Well I soaked uncooked rice , urad dal and chana together at 7 am and now at 5am I completely forgot about it !  What sould I do ? Is it safe , if I do it now ?

Comment: Was it refrigerated?

Comment: Was it completely submerged in water the whole time ?

Comment: @AJN submerged in water or not doesn't mitigate the food safety issue (unless it was completely dry, which is clearly not the case).  It is a question of temperature.  Refrigerated = this would be safe.  Un-refrigerated in this time frame = potential for pathogen growth.

Comment: Yes, although presumably the OP is still going to cook them before eating.